# Real Time Speech-To-Text Application using socket-io

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, real-time, flask-socketio

We are trying to build a web application. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume there will be a frontend application (e.g. React app) and a backend application (e.g. Flask). We will collect the speech from the microphone through the frontend application and send it to the backend application in real-time (actually with an acceptable delay). Backend application creates text using some ai models and pushes the text content to the frontend application in real-time. I though that we can use socket-io for transmitting audio in real-time but I couldn't imagine a well-defined architecture.

Do you know how to build such application ? All ideas are welcome. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example application that records audio in the frontend (vanilla JS), sends it to the back end (Flask), which in turn writes it to a .wav file.

The repository is https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/socketio-examples. There are a few Socket.IO demo apps in there. The one you want is in the `audio` directory.

I gave a presentation at a conference where I discuss these demos a few years ago. Here is the section about audio: https://youtu.be/Jwux1TPZUwg?si=SxX8XYvnLV_j0yTV&t=991

Comment: I want to ask something. Does backend (Flask) writes to .wav file on the way ? I mean, does it writes while audio stream is continuously being send from frontend ? Or, does it writes to file after whole stream is transferred to backend ? I need to know this because we aim to push this audio stream to an ai model in a continuous fashion.

Comment: It writes the chunks of audio as they arrive.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to rely on an API for the real-time ASR component, you might want to check assemblyAI's api. Here you can test it on the playground: https://www.assemblyai.com/playground

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for online speech recognition use remote procedure call (gRPC)
this [example](https://github.com/Open-Speech-EkStep/speech-recognition-open-api) may be helpful